# How to select random 100 records in HP Vertica?

Tags: sql, vertica

What function is used to select top 100 random records of a table in Vertica?

In Sybase we use something like

```
Select top 100 * from table_name a order by rand(rowid(a))
```

Comment: `Select * from table order by random() limit 100`?

Comment: This Worked and yep its pretty simple!

Comment: I thought I was missing something.  Thus a comment vs an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's pretty similar:

```
select * from table_name a order by RANDOM() LIMIT 100
```

There's that curious thing called *a manual*; it's full of [little](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#11476.htm) [gems](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#2987.htm) like this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and yep thanks for sharing these manual link.